# How can I use a lookup table for brightness and contrast?

Tags: c#, unity, color, image-processing

Currently, I implemented a rudimentary brightness and contrast algorithm that changes brightness and contrast pixel by pixel. This was super inefficient performance wise and the algorithm looked a bit strange.

I heard that I can use a lookup table to get values brightness and contrast for a texture 2D image. How can I do something like this in Unity?

Currently in Unity, I have a prefab in which I load a texture 2D image on top of it. That's the image i want to apply brightness and contrast changes to.

Comment: Can you post your current code? On a modern system it would probably be a wash between a look-up table or just doing the math. So if you've profiled it and found that it truly is your brightness/contrast adjustment that's slow, let's see what that looks like.

Comment: less than a wash, the math doesn't cost memory latency

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
public void addContrast(float Contrast)
{
    byte[] contrast_lookup = new byte[256];
    double newValue = 0;
    double c = (100.0 + Contrast) / 100.0;

    c *= c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        newValue = (double)i;
        newValue /= 255.0;
        newValue -= 0.5;
        newValue *= c;
        newValue += 0.5;
        newValue *= 255;

        if (newValue < 0)
            newValue = 0;
        if (newValue > 255)
            newValue = 255;
        contrast_lookup[i] = (byte)newValue;
    }
}
```

At this point , for each pixel yuo replace G B R with contrast_lookup(G)  contrast_lookup(B) contrast_lookup(R)

Comment: Do I need to change each pixel if I'm using a lookup table? Wouldn't that be slow? Also, how do I access the color curves lookup table in Unity?

Comment: sorry .. never eart of "color curves lookup table" in Unity

Comment: No problem. Btw, what do you mean by, "At this point , for each pixel yuo replace G B R with contrast_lookup(G) contrast_lookup(B) contrast_lookup(R)"?

Comment: And how would you do it for brightness?

Comment: let t be your texture2d  then:                for (int i = 0; i < wid; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < hei; j++)
                    {
                        t.SetPixel(i,j,contrast_lookup(t.GetPixel(i,j));
                    }
                }

Comment: And how would you do it for brightness?  Use a negative float Contrast in addContrast. Contrast goes from -100f to 100f

Comment: SetPixel() is fairly slow. You'll either want to batch it up using SetPixels(), or better, do this with a Shader as an image effect on the GPU - this is exactly the kind of thing your graphics hardware was made to do.